# eMMC interface SDIO2 of EC200U

Tags: memory, embedded, embedded-linux, quectel

I am interfacing eMMC([THGBMJG6C1LBAU7](https://www.kioxia.com/content/dam/kioxia/shared/business/memory/mlc-nand/asset/productbrief/KIOXIA_e-MMC_Product_Brief.pdf)) memory with [EC200U](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-ec200u-series) from Quectel.

The Quectel E200U has two SDIO ports.I used SDIO2 for connecting my eMMC memory.

In the hardware design document they have shown WLAN interface with SDIO2.Please see the image below.

[image]

Does that mean SDIO2 will work only for WLAN?
Do we need to make any changes in the Kernel for eMMC to work?

Comment: "*Does that mean SDIO2 will work only for WLAN.*" - You need to punctuate your questions with a `question mark` rather than a `period`. Consult the SoC datasheet from Quectel for an answer. "*Do we need to make any changes in the Kernel for eMMC to work.*" - That's what the Device Tree is for (assuming that there are Linux kernel drivers for your SoC devices).